# Querying employee schedules in a month

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, sql-server, .net-datatable

I have this code, this code querying employee schedules in a month, in a work unit. If the `List<Employee>` count are few, the code works great, but if the `List<Employee>` count are many, the code runs slowly.  How I can optimize this code?

The `DataRow` is datagrid row containing employee id, name, etc..

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    List<Employee> employees = DatabaseHelper.GetEmployees(unitId, false, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
    {
        int no = i + 1;
        DataRow row = DataTableJadwal.Rows.Add(no + ".", employees[i].Nama, employees[i].ID);
        DatabaseHelper.GetUserSchedules(ref row, month, year);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(300);
});

public static void GetUserSchedules(ref DataRow row, int month, int year)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(string.Format(constring, UserID, Password, Server, Database)))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT Date, Shift FROM ScheduleList WHERE (ID = @ID) AND (MONTH(Date) = @Month) AND (YEAR(Date) = @Year)"
            , sqlConn))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row["ID"]);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", month);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);

                sqlConn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    int totalHour = 0;
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        DateTime dt = (DateTime)sqlReader["Date"];
                        string shift = (string)sqlReader["Shift"];

                        // a user may had 1,2,3 schedule a day
                        string cellText = row[dt.Day.ToString("00")].ToString();
                        if (cellText.Length < 1)
                            cellText = shift;
                        else
                            cellText += "," + shift;

                        // count schedule hour total
                        if (Utilities.FreeScheduleList.IndexOf(shift.ToUpper()) == -1)
                        {
                            if (shift == "M" || shift == "Q")
                                totalHour += 10;
                            else
                                totalHour += 7;
                        }

                        row[dt.Day.ToString("00")] = cellText;
                    }

                    row["Total"] = totalHour;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message, "GetUserSchedules Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do some benchmarks to figure out what instructions make your code slow?

Comment: I do not know how to do that, I never do that before,

Comment: Without benchmarks it's just guessing. `Thread.Sleep(300);` what are you waiting for here?

Comment: I show some progress loading when loading the data, to anticipate flashing the progress, when data to load is few, I add 300 ms sleep so the minimum loading time is 300 ms

Comment: after some research, I found that the sql query running almost 100 ms, so if I have 70 employee, that is nearly 7 seconds

Comment: @SIRS Do you mean `sqlComm.ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: I would try optimizing two things first - share connection and command object between calling the same request only with different parameters values. Haven't been using this for a long time, but I think it shall be doable...
The another way - I'd just join first select (GetEmployees) with second select (GetUserSchedules) into one command and iterate through returned rows. You then have some redundancy, but this is common when optimizing queries.

Comment: I don't think this is working code.   row in DatabaseHelper.GetUserSchedules(ref row, month, year); is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create index on your table as @RobH suggestion

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ScheduleList_Id_Date on your_schema.ScheduleList
(
    Id,
    Date,
    Shift
)
```

Then as @Paparazzi suggestion change your query so you only need to call it once,

```
SELECT e.ID, nama, Date, Shift 
  FROM Employee e 
  JOIN ScheduleList s
    ON s.ID = e.ID
   AND e.unitId = @UnitId
   AND s.Date >= @StartDate 
   AND s.Date < @AndDate
```

Then filter the result in your code, it should be something like this.

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    string ID = sqlReader.GetString(0);
    var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ID") == ID);
    if (rows.Count() < 1)
    {
        // add row if row is not exist
        num += 1;
        string Nama = sqlReader.GetString(1);
        row = dataTable.Rows.Add(num + ".", Nama, ID);

        row["Total"] = 0;
    }
    else { row = rows.First(); }

    // YOUR CODE
    // ....
}
```

Don't forget to pass the `DataTable`, not the `DataRow`

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    DatabaseHelper.GetEmployeeAndSchedules(ref DataTable, unitId, month, year);
    Thread.Sleep(300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @nyongrand that code boost the execution time from ~7 sec to ~2

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to avoid raging about the data table based data access layer because I doubt a random person on the internet is going to change the direction of your project. So, let's look at your SQL query:

```sql
SELECT Date, 
       Shift 
FROM   ScheduleList 
WHERE  ID = @ID 
  AND  MONTH(Date) = @Month
  AND  YEAR(Date) = @Year
```

I've removed the extra brackets because they were just adding noise. This query could easily be changed so you could add a covering index to your schedule list table:

```sql
SELECT Date, 
       Shift 
FROM   ScheduleList 
WHERE  ID = @ID 
  AND  Date > @Date
  AND  Date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)
```

Combined with an index on the `Date` and `Id` columns which also includes `Shift` and your query will be much faster.

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_ScheduleList_Id_Date on your_schema.ScheduleList
(
    Id,
    Date
) INCLUDE (Shift)
```

I'd be more inclined to do this though:

```sql
SELECT Date, 
       Shift 
FROM   ScheduleList 
WHERE  ID = @ID 
  AND  Date > @StartDate
  AND  Date < @EndDate
```

This way you can search for schedule list in any window of time, not just one month at a time.

Having said that, what I'd actually do is return the employee list with their schedules at the same time - SQL is a *relational* database: it's good at joining related data together.

(SQL typed into browser and I'm rusty so it might not be 100% right).

Comment: I use sql 2000, so instead I use `CREATE INDEX IX_ScheduleList_Id_Date on your_schema.ScheduleList(Id, Date, Shift)` is that right? after using your suggestion, the time needed decrease from ~100 ms to ~60ms

Comment: @SIRS - it's **2017** why are you still using SQL 2000? As far as I know, 2000 hasn't been supported since 2013. You should upgrade to a later (supported) version of SQL Server.

Comment: I did not do programming for my self, everything was setup and I can't just change the thing, sometimes it's easier to live with a decision you don't like

Comment: @SIRS - easier isn't the same as better. I would hope you would at least tell them that it's not good that they're relying on such old software.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)sqlReader["Date"];
```

This is faster

```
DateTime dt = sqlReader.GetDate(0);

string shift = sqlReader.GetString(1);
```

Create and open the connection once and pass it to GetUserSchedules

Indexes cannot be used with MONTH(Date) = @Month

```
SELECT Date, 
       Shift 
FROM   ScheduleList 
WHERE  ID = @ID 
  AND  Date > @start
  AND  Date < @end

sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", new DateTime(year, month, 0);
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", new DateTime(year, month + 1, 0));
```

I bet you can do this with one query

```
SELECT e.ID, nama, Date, Shift 
  FROM Employee e 
  JOIN ScheduleList s
    ON s.ID = e.ID
   AND e.unitId = x 
   AND s.Date > DateTime(year, month, 0) 
   AND s.Date < DateTime(year, month + 1, 0)
```

Use sqlCmd for command.  sqlComm looks too much like sqlConn.  Use sqlCon.